# Focused component when tabbing has no visual indication of focus

Tags: java, swing, focus

I've a `JDialog` on which I've added different components (`JButton`, `JTextField`, `JRadioButton` etc). It runs fine, functions as desired, while using keyboard to interact with the UI when I use TAB key it iterates over all components **but the problem is** - not all component's focus is visible on the UI.

### For Example:

When tab key pressed and next component is a text field cursor starts blinking in it, tab pressed again and next component in line is a radio button the focus on that radio button is not visible in the mean time if I press Space Bar to select this radio button it gets selected.

Similarly focus is not visible for next inline button or combo box but pressing space bar to select it presses the button and drops down the combo box option respectively.

### Meaning:

Pressing tab iterates focus over all the components as required but is not visible for all of them

Comment: 1) You've described a problem, but asked no question. What is your question? 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: `the focus on that radio button is not visible` - I have never seen that problem. The LAF determines how the focus is indicated. Typically there is a dotted line around the text of the radio button. As indicated above post your code demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I wanna know about this unusual behaviour that focus is not visible, although its working. just not visible.

Comment: @AlphaTry, and the problem would be your code. I can't possibly guess why it has worked for me for 15 years but it is not working for you. If you can't post your simple code of a JFrame with two radio buttons that displays the problem then we can't offer any suggestions. If you want help then make an effort!!!

Comment: @camickr, I know, I've tried doing it separately as well, and it works. but not in the code i'm trying to fix. and it is 2000 plus liner code. cant paste it here off course.

Comment: (1-)  @AlphaTry `and it is 2000 plus liner code` - well 2000 lines of code is not used to create the dialog so you need to isolate the problem. If you can't isolate we can't help. This is why you test code incrementally. You write a little and test and then repeat. You don't write 2000 lines before you start testing. If you can't give us any information to work with we can't help.

Comment: Yes sir, as mentioned previously. The functional behaviour is spot on. and tested, working fine. Its just the visibility with the focused component.

my currentJdialog class i'm trying to sort extends a predefined custom made parentJdialog class which just contains common button to maintain the consistency of the dialog that appears in the Application.. and this parentJdialog class extends Jdialog class that Java provides.

Comment: @AlphaTry, the functional behaviour is completely irrelevant to your stated question. You question is about a radio button on a frame.

Comment: @camickr, I'm using a custom MetroLAF which extents MetalLAF. And the reason why it doesn't showing focus on a component is because focus colour is not defined in the MetroLAF. I need to set focus colour so that it could get rendered.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using a custom MetroLAF which extents MetalLAF

And there is absolutely no way we could know that from your original question which is why you need to post a `SSCCE` with every question so we can see what you are doing.

Since you are using a non standard class the problem is with that class. Since you still haven't posted a SSCCE with the code of this non standard class we still can't help you. You need to debug the code yourself or use the Metal LAF.

> focus colour is not defined in the MetroLAF

Well it is defined in the Metal LAF so since Metro extends from Metal is should be defined. If not, then it is up to you to set the color.

You can take a look at [UIManager Default](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) which shows the default values for each LAF. It also shows how to set a value. Of course setting a value will only work if the code uses the value.

Comment: It turns out, The componentUI classes like MetroRadioButtonUI in my case that needs to get register in the MetroLNF class  method  initClassDefaults(UIDefaults table) didn't had the paintFocus() method defined in the implementation.

I added the missing paintFocus() method in the respective UI classes, and adjusted its calls like defined in  RadioButtonUI. and it worked out fine.